# Equivalence of weak and weak-* convergence for sequences and reflexivity

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $X^*$ its topological dual space. Let us define the property (WS):

> For all sequences $(x_n^*) \subset X^*$ and all $x^* \in X^*$, we have
> $$x_n^* \rightharpoonup x^* \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad x_n^* \stackrel*\rightharpoonup x^*,$$
> i.e., weak and weak-* convergence of sequences are equivalent in $X^*$.

It is clear that reflexive spaces have the property (WS). Moreover, if $X$ is separable and has (WS), then one can show that $X$ is reflexive, see [this MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2653653).

What happens if $X$ is not separable?

To add a little bit of context:
It is a classical result, that reflexivity is equivalent to the equality of the weak topology and the weak-* topology on $X^*$. However, the topologies are not determined by the convergent sequences.

Similar question arise also for strong and weak convergence, but seems to be easier to answer. The coincidence of the strong topology and the weak topology is equivalent to the space being finite dimensional. However, in $\ell^1$ weak and strong convergence of sequences coincides (Schur property).

Comment: This is a characterization of the Grothendieck property for $X$. For example, $\ell_\infty$ has this property. See https://arxiv.org/abs/2102.03838 for a recent survey on this topic.